# A Problem on Locally Convex Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

In the book *A Course in Functional Analysis* by Conway, there is the following problem:

> **Problem.** Let $ X $ be a completely regular topological space, and let $ C(X) $ denote the set of all continuous functions from $ X $ to $ \mathbb{F} \in \{ \mathbb{R},\mathbb{C} \} $. If $ K $ is a compact subset of $ X $, define
>   $$
> {p_{K}}(f) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \sup(\{ |f(x)| \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \mid x \in K \}).
> $$
>   Then prove that
>   $$
>   \bigcap_{\text{$ K \subseteq X $ is compact}} \{ f \in C(X) \mid {p_{K}}(f) = 0 \}
> = \{ 0_{C(X)} \}.
> $$

Could anyone kindly help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry , I type wrong . You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is $f\in  C(X)$ such that for every compact subset $K$, $p_K(f)=\sup_{x\in K}f(x) =0  $. For every $x\in X$, the set $\{x\}$ is compact so $p_{\{x\}}(f)=0$ which shows that $f=0$ on $X$.

Comment: Why {x} is compact?

Comment: @CPat: because every open cover of it has a finite subcover